# Master page error on adding?

Tags: asp.net

I a trying to add New Master Page in fresh project throw 'Add new Items" while adding i have this Error "`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1. Position` 1" 
How to solve this please ?

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried closing Visual Studio and re-opening it?

Comment: yes everytime same error

Comment: are your master page successfully added to the project?

Comment: The problem probably lies with an xml-file somewhere. Is the web.config file correct?

Comment: WebForm adding successfully just problem with Master page

Comment: When you add a new page to the project, do you check the "select master page"? Could you dump a picture of the problem and/or your file structure?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can reproduce your error in my environment.
The problem is occured if you have an invalid XML file in your project. Probably the web.config.

Can you confirm that the XML files in your project is well formed? Try to open the XML file using IE and ensuring that there are no errors.

Comment: my project is super fresh without any other file first thing i am adding that is master page which is giving error!